# Correting wrong insert-from-select SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

here is a mysql statement, can you please tell what is wrong with it

```
insert into wip_inventory
(wip_inventory.amount)
values (
  select
  sum(planning.actual_cost) as c
  from planning
  where planning.progress='no'
)
```

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong with it?

Comment: Welcome to the site! The way it works around here is exactly the other way around, though: you tell what's going on, and the community helps you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need two sets of parentheses to express this logic using `values` (one for the `values` list and one for the subquery).  But, that keyword is superfluous anyway:

```
insert into wip_inventory (wip_inventory.amount)
    select sum(planning.actual_cost) as c
    from planning
    where planning.progress = 'no';
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query only one record will be added to `wip_inventory` and will throw error if the subquery returns more than one record.
I think you are trying to insert all records returned from subquery so, use `INSERT INTO SELECT`:

```
insert into wip_inventory (wip_inventory.amount) 
select sum(planning.actual_cost) as c 
from planning 
where planning.progress='no'
```